# Phonegap can't pair tablet and desktop app or command line, Phonegap server never receives any calls.

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to set up an app using Phonegap but I can't get pairing with my tablet to work. Both are connected to my local wireless network. When I attempt to access the ip on the phonegap app nothing happens in the server logs:

```
[phonegap] starting app server...
[phonegap] listening on 127.94.0.1:3000
[phonegap] 
[phonegap] ctrl-c to stop the server
[phonegap]
```

And I receive an error message on the tablet: `Unable to Download Archive from the server Unable to properly connect to the server`

I've tried disconnecting and reconnecting both and restarting the server, but nothing seems to help at all. I am running the most recent versions of the app and the node package.

Comment: Check my answer on this. This solved the issue for me. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703759/phonegap-unable-to-download-archive-from-the-server/40138140#40138140

Answer (score 0):

Try running `phonegap serve --localtunnel` then use the tunnel url that gets generated on your phone app to connect.