# Phonegap - Unable to download archive from the server

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to run the phone gap application from my Phonegap Developer app. But getting error "Unable to download archive from the server". 
I am connecting to the ip address which is shown in Phone gap Desktop application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The PhoneGap desktop app showed the message "Server is running on http://192.168.56.1:3000," so I entered that IP address in the mobile app. This didn't work because my computer is behind a router.

I ran ipconfig from the command line (in Windows) and I saw the following line:

```
 IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.10
```

So I entered 10.0.0.10:3000 instead of the public IP address, and it worked.

Comment: I had the same issue but 192.168.56.1 is the ip address of the virtual network card created by Virtual Box. I used the actual ip address of my ethernet network card and it works.

Comment: This helped in pointing me towards a different solution for my situation... being the idiot I am, I had my phone and computer connecting to different wifi networks. Obviously ensuring they are on the same network should be the first step.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem...  I could run the templates that came with PhoneGap Desktop just fine. But my big app that I had built with PhoneGap 1.3 would not run on the iPhone nor Android. It crashed the PhoneGap Developer on Android, and just kept trying to Download forever on the iPhone. I tried everything that I could find. Finally I decided to change the port from 3000 to 4000. It worked!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue but fixed the problem with following:

1. My phone and laptop were **not** connected to same wifi. Later I realized this and connected them to same wifi. So check it first.
2. Then the next mistake I was doing is the ip address. When I typed `phonegap serve` it was actually showing 3 different ip addresses where the app is listening. Out of them one is the ip address of the wireless adapter.

Instead of using the **wireless** adapter IP, I was using the **Ethernet** adapter IP. So, if you are connected to wireless, first type `ipconfig` (in windows) and check the wireless adapter IP and use that. It should work.